# How do I connect Watson Knowledge Catalog (WKC) to my Oracle Cloud ATP database?

Tags: workflow, watson-knowledge-catalog

I am trying to connect Watson Knowledge Catalog (WKC) to my Oracle Cloud ATP database. In the WKC connection screen it asks for these params:
- "Host name or IP address" - I'm trying to hit my Oracle ATP database on Oracle Cloud, so what would be the hostname or IP address?
- "Port" - I'm trying to hit Oracle cloud database, so what is the Port? 
- "Service name" - again would this be for an Oracle cloud database?
- "Database (SID)" - I assume this is the "Database name" on the Oracle cloud database, correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Cloud ATP is currently not supported.